/.well-known/pki-validation/fileauth.txt 404 nginx
so my sites-enable/defult currently looks like this
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  server_tokens off;

  location /custom/.well-known {
    alias /srv/custom/.well-known;
    allow all;
    default_type "text/plain";
    autoindex    on;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}

# SSL configuration
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
  server_name _;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
  include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  client_max_body_size 40M;
  server_tokens off;
  root /srv/custom;

  include /etc/nginx/apps/*.conf;

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}




root is changed to /srv/custom/ and i have added that too the .wellknown however i still recive a 404 error
i have tried many varations from incling srv at the start and leaving aliass without the /custom/ and any other variation i could think off
